# Need to write test case for MongoDB Realm Swift SDK

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm

I am working on MongoDB Realm Swift SDk and I need to write the test case for the login function which is as below:

```
let params: Document = ["username": "bob"]
app.login(credentials: Credentials.function(payload: params)) { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Login failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    case .success(let user):
        print("Successfully logged in as user \(user)")
        // Now logged in, do something with user
        // Remember to dispatch to main if you are doing anything on the UI thread
    }
}
```

May I know how to write test case for this function with Mock Data so that I can verify that Login is working fine?

Comment: The question is unclear - are you asking for us to provide code for you or something else? Did you try the code? Is it not working as intended? What's the issue with the code in the question?

Comment: My code needs to make server request which in response provides me the userId which I need. How can I write the test case for this kind of requests?  As far as I know unit test cases should not depend on outside world.

Comment: @Jay Anything you got?

Comment: At the moment the only thing that comes to mind is that users are cached. So for testing, logging in once will create the cached user and then after that you can use the cached user for unit testing.

Comment: @Jay Yes I did the same and I think this is the only way to test the Login Functionality. Thanks!